# UI components for touch screen winforms applications?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, controls, touchscreen

I have seen this question: 
[Are there any decent UI components for touch screen web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134067/are-there-any-decent-ui-components-for-touch-screen-web-applications) and have allmost exact the same question but Im focused on winforms.

I working on an application that is not primary made for using with a touch screen, but now I see more and more customers using touch screen and want the application to support it better.

I want to "add" to the UI so that for example a rightclick on a combobox (or click a button at the side of the combobox) opens up a dialogbox that handles the showing and selecting of the items easier on a touch screen.

Controls I want to enhance or replace are listboxes, comboboxes and textboxes.

I know its easy to create those controls myself, but I think there must be some standards and allready tested UIs that works good in that environment. I dont want to reinvent the wheel and make a bad one if it allready exists good ones.

To sum it up: 
Are there guide-lines for controls regarding touch screens, then where?
Are there any allready made controls I can byu (or free ones) out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found some information:

**Interaction Design Guide for Touchscreen Applications**
http://www.sapdesignguild.org/resources/TSDesignGL/INDEX.HTM
**pdf-version:**
http://www.sapdesignguild.org/resources/TSDesignGL/TSDesignGL.pdf

**The interface between humans and interactive kiosks**
http://www.visi.com/~keefner/pdfs/focus1.pdf

**Keys to a Successful Kiosk Application**  Some tips can be used generally:
http://www.visi.com/~keefner/pdfs/Kiosk-Tips.ppt

Comment: sadly all of these are dead or half dead links